# Trailing edge tapered and leading edge straight

Tags: stall, glider, sailplane

It is true that a wing with a straight leading edge and a tapered trailing edge has good stall characteristics?. That is, we can assure that when it enters stall, it will first be at the root and then at the tip. The most similar information I can find is with wings with sweep from the roots and the rectangular, but I don't know if that specific type works similarly.
[image: https://www.alexander-schleicher.de/en/flugzeuge/asw-20-baureihe/]

Comment: Re "The most similar information I can find is with wings with sweep from the roots and the blocks" -- what do you mean by "the blocks"?

Comment: "we can assure that when it enters stall, it will first be at the root and then at the tip" -- This is what [washout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washout_(aeronautics)) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sweeping a wing can change the shape of the load distribution and the pattern of stall (inboard vs. outboard), the amount of sweep you get by holding a high aspect ratio wing like this straight at the LE vs. c/4 vs. TE is pretty insignificant (about 3.5 deg.) and is not an effective way of changing the stall characteristics.

Instead, on a high aspect ratio wing, you would use washout and taper to tailor the load distribution and stall behavior.  This wing has a reasonable amount of taper, and will need some washout to push the stall inboard a bit.